# Trying to validate textbox in update mode (entered date must be > today)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to validate the `TextBox` in update mode: (entered date must > today)

```
<asp:TemplateField SortExpression="enddat">
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="enddat" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("enddat","{0:dd-MM-yy}") %>' CausesValidation="true" ></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CustomValidator ID="compare1" ValidateEmptyText="true" runat="server" EnableClientScript="false" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="enddat" ErrorMessage="must be after today">
</asp:CustomValidator>
```

In code-behind:

```
 Protected Sub GridView1_RowUpdating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewUpdateEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowUpdating

 Dim row As GridViewRow = CType(GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex), GridViewRow)

 Dim enddat As TextBox = CType(row.FindControl("enddat"), TextBox)
 Dim val As CustomValidator = CType(row.FindControl("compare1"), CustomValidator)
 dat = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yy")

        If Convert.ToDateTime(enddat.Text) < dat Then
            val.IsValid = False
        End If
End Sub
```

Nothing happens! It accepts all data. What is wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with asp validation but I can show how to validate a date.

Dates are difficult. To do comparisons, it is best to keep the data as a `Date` (or `DataTime`) datatype. Trying to compare a String formatted as a date with a < or > can cause problems.

I used the `.TryParse` method to first determine if the input is a valid date. The `AndAlso` in the `If` statement "short-cuircuits" the if by stopping as soon a it finds a False condition. Trying to compare a non valid date to a date would cause an exception. The second condition is never tested if the first condition fails.

```
Dim IsValid As Boolean
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dat = DateTime.Now.Date
    Dim DateInTextBox As Date
    If Date.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, DateInTextBox) AndAlso DateInTextBox.Date = dat Then
        IsValid = True
    Else
        IsValid = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Just for testing, all of these returned True.

```
November 4, 2020
11/4/2020
Nov 4, 2020
11/04/2020 7PM
```

The format should only matter for display purposes not comparison. If you want to put a preferred format back into the textbox call `.ToString` on `DateInTextBox` with the appropriate format string.